# R Class of Function Output

Tags: r, function, types, functional-programming, output

What is the best way to get the class of a function's output in R? Formals works for the inputs, but not sure on the outputs.

Consider

```
f_1 <- function(x) {
    x
}
f_2 <- function(x) {
    list(x, x ^ 2)
}
```

If I could call a function, call it output, such that output(`f_1`) returns "numeric" and output(`f_2`) returns "list", then that would be sufficient.

In particular, I want to write a function that takes a function as an argument and then produces a new function as a result, but what that function is depends on the class of the output of the first function. Might be better explained by an example.

```
f_3 <- function(f, neg=FALSE) {
    if (neg==FALSE) {
        f
    } else {
        force(f)
        if (output(f) == "list") { #output(f) is just something 
            #I made up, doesn't actually work
            function(x) {
                lapply(f(x), function(y) y * -1)
            }
        } else {
            function(x) {
                f(x) * -1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If neg is false, `f_3` just reproduces the function. As noted in the comment, since the output(f) part doesn't exist, the rest of it doesn't either. If it did, then it would multiply the results of f(x) by -1 or use lapply to do the same thing, depending on the class of the output of f(x).

Comment: have a look at `?class`, for instance `class(f_1)` will return "function". `x<-c(1:10)` and  `class(x)` will return "integer" and `class(list(1:10))` will return "list"

Comment: I know class. That doesn't solve my issue. I want to have the class of the output of the function. Not the class function.

Comment: so you can just call class on the function with the arguument to function `class(f(x))`

Comment: If I add in after the force(f) line, the command class_f <- class(f(x)) and then replace the output(f) with class_f, then I get an error that there is no x.

Comment: well you're not passing x in the call to f_3, so it's not going to fin d it.

Comment: How would you like this function to handle `f_1`? It seems to me you could put in anything (numeric, data.frame. formula etc.) and get the same class back out.

Comment: @JohnPaul I was just using `f_1` as an example of the simplest function I could think of. For this simple example, it would be something like `x <- 1; g <- f_3(f_1, neg=TRUE); g(x)` would produce 1 and `x <- 1; g <- f_3(f_1, neg=FALSE); g(x)` would produce -1, but then also adjust so that for `f_2` it would work properly with lists as an output.